# Why does my function need parentheses?

Tags: angularjs, components

In my framework, the functions are called without parentheses.... (See showErrors)

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('core')
    .directive('showErrors', showErrors);

  showErrors.$inject = ['$timeout', '$interpolate'];

  function showErrors($timeout, $interpolate) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^form',
      compile: compile
    };

    return directive;
```

I get how it works... but when I try this, my component won't work. It only works if I change it to  .component('hotkeys', HotkeysComponent()); // adding parenthesis to HotkeysComponent

```
  angular
    .module('contacts.components')
    .component('hotkeys', HotkeysComponent);

  function HotkeysComponent() {
    var component = {
      templateUrl: '/my-app/contacts/client/views/ui/hotkeys.ui.html',
      controller: 'AddManagerController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return component;
```

To clarify, it won't work unless I do HotkeysComponent()

```
angular
  .module('contacts.components')
  .component('hotkeys', HotkeysComponent()); // why don't the other functions need ()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can be registered using the `.component()` method of an AngularJS module (returned by `angular.module()`). The method takes two arguments:

- The name of the Component (as string).
- The Component config object. (Note that, unlike the `.directive()`
  method, this method does not take a factory function.)

As per your question, the second argument must be an object and that happens only when you called the function(second argument)

[Components in angular js](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)
read this for more info

Comment: Mr_Perfect, can I ask you a few follow up questions via chat?

Comment: Please go through the documentation first, then ask me. Everything will be there clearly

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between the two. `HotkeysComponent` as a parameter gives the function pointer, while `HotkeysComponent()` is the value `HotkeysComponent` returns.

An example:

```
testFunction(variable) {
    variable();
}

testFunction(alert);
```

Here we pass alert as a function (not the return value). Now we can execute this function inside `testFunction`.

```
testFunction(variable) {
    console.log(variable);
}

sum(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

testFunction(sum(10,20));
```

Here we pass the outcome of the sum function to the function, which we can use inside our testFunction.

Comment: isn't 'return directive' just making an object, like { templateUrl: ... }